# Avoid duplication of steps across multiple pools in azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a netstandard library that I want to build and test across multiple platforms (Windows & Linux).

Currently I have to do this

```
jobs:
  - job: Linux
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
    steps:
        # A number of steps here

  - job: Windows
    pool:
      vmImage: vs2017-win2016
    steps:
        # The exact same steps as the linux job
```

Is there any way to avoid having to duplicate the steps between the jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am afraid that you have to set the steps separately for each pool if across multiple pools in azure pipelines.

However you can try using **template**. A single step can be defined in one file and used multiple places in another file.

Please see [YAML schema reference - Step template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=vsts#step-template) for details.

```
# File: steps/build.yml

steps:
- script: npm install
- script: npm test
```

Across multiple pools:

```
# File: azure-pipelines.yml

jobs:
- job: macOS
  pool:
    vmImage: 'macOS-10.13'
  steps:
  - template: steps/build.yml # Template reference

- job: Linux
  pool:
    vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
  steps:
  - template: steps/build.yml # Template reference

- job: Windows
  pool:
    vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'
  steps:
  - template: steps/build.yml # Template reference
  - script: sign              # Extra step on Windows only
```